# Pass command output to a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, sed

I want to pass the output of a Sed command to a variable in batch.
For example, in the file "input.txt" I have `name=kiddy bla bla`.
I want to extract the the word `kiddy` and save it in a variable (say, `name`), so I can use it later (with `%name%`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can set a variable with the output of a `sed` command with a `for` loop:

```
for /f %%v in ('sed blah blah...') do (set "name=%%v")
```

Yes, it's not so intuitive, but it works.
Also, you can change the command to anything you want, as long as it's between 
apostrophes (`'`).

P.S
To extract the value `kiddy` from `name="kiddy" bla bla`, use such `sed` syntax:

```
sed "s/""/'/g" | sed "s/.*='\(.[^']*\)'.*/\1/"
```

Comment: for the extracting thing, this work if kiddy was between "" , like "kiddy" ?

Comment: @Leo92 This works only for "kiddy" or 'kiddy'. Look at the Sed script.

Comment: ok , i am trying to change name with name" using sed, sed "s/name/name"/g" but it giving me error , I tried putting \ before "" error tired with ^ before " again error , I dont know what to do to skip it ,

Comment: @Leo92 `"` is not escaped in batch in the same way it is escaped in Sed. Working with quotation marks (`"`) is not really recommended in batch scripts, because the batch interpreter tries to handle them itself, so you sometimes get unexpected results. Use apostrophes (`'`) in your strings instead.